# Removing Drawing Rectangle from UIView in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I used to create rectangles inside of a UIView (e.g: '**candleContainer**') by using the following code:

```
UIView *myBox  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(marginX, marginY, rectWidth, rectHeight)];
[self.candleContainer addSubview:myBox];
```

But how do I remove all or each rectangles which were already drawn. I did it by removing the **'candleContainer'** UIView from the super view. But that's not the actual solution, right?. I want to remove only those rectangles. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 NSArray *viewsToRemove = [self.view subviews];

    for (UIView *view in viewsToRemove) {

        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have to fetch all UIView objects From **self.candleContainer** ! then remove it from self.candleContainer.

```
for (UIView *view in self.candleContainer) 
{
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Or you can add tag to UIView object! and then you can fetch it by viewWithTag: method then remove it From self.candleContainer!